# I want Microsoft power automate to reply to message and skip the update message

Tags: power-automate

I have a flow that when tag is mentioned calls an external server to get a form on a adaptive card.  That card is then filled out and when user clicks submit, form data is sent to webserver.  The webserver responds with results of the post.  I want to print those in another adaptive card in the original message.  What I don't want to do, is have the original adaptive card post the value of "Update Message" in the card settings.  Basically i dont want "Confirm results in next message" to show up in a seperate message.  How do i avoid that message being sent at 11:35 completely?

Here is my flow:

[image]

and here is the result.[image]

Comment: I'm happy to be proven wrong but I don't think you can.  If you want to do something like that then you should look at using modals in Slack.  Adaptive cards in Teams aren't as advanced.  It's more request and response than a state based mini application that can be modified when the user presses buttons, etc.